# Footable shows 01.01.1970 for null values

Tags: momentjs, footable, columnsorting

I'm trying to sort a FooTable table on a date column which also has null values, outputted as empty strings. I have included moment.js before footable and footable.sorting in my HTML. My null values are displayed and sorted as 01.01.1970. There are no js console errors. Anyone able to point me in the right direction as to how to fix this?

```
<table class="footable table table-striped" data-sorting="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>(...)</th>
        <th data-type="date" data-format-string="DD.MM.YYYY">Invoice Date</th>
        <th>(...)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, but it is showing December 31, 1969 for blank dates. -- FooTable v3.1.5

Comment: I'm at UTC. Your problem sounds like the same issue only on a different time zone? I have FooTable 3.1.6 and Moment.js 2.18.1

Comment: I ended up not specifying the datatype as date and consider it a string.  Added datetime ticks for data-sort-value, and formatted string for data-filter-value.  I did not rely on the footable data-format-string as the datatype date was removed.

Comment: @sjur did you try formatter, the example i provided. this is all for formating parts.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing what @barrypicker did, treating it as string and sorting by ticks.

Answer (score 0):

https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html#column-formatter

Use column formatter and put custom checks of Null. All will work ok.